# C incomplete Type in structs

Tags: c, struct, typedef, incomplete-type

He folks,
i got a problem and a question.
Hopefully u can help and explain me.

first of all i have 2 stucts:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} A;

typedef struct  {
    unsigned int count;
    A(*stack)[]; 
}B;
```

this struct B i declare in main() and passing a Pointer of B to a function this will initializ

```
main(){
    B x;
    function rr(&x);
}

void rr(B* test) {
   test->stack= malloc((4) * sizeof(A)); //4Elements
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        (test->stack+ i)->x= 89;        
    }
}
```

on this line
(test->stack+ i)->x= 89;
compiler says incomplete Type
i know why it is incomplete cause in struct B their is no dimension.
but array should initialize in function rr

Maybe u understand what i mean and how to solve my problem.
function rr i am not allowed to change.

Greetings

EDIT 1
Thank you for all answers
mabey i schould clearify my problem

```
typedef struct  {
    unsigned int count;
    A(*stack)[]; // here i want a pointer to an array of A's
}B;


//over main it is declared
void rr(B*);


main(){
    B x;
    function rr(&x);
}

// this func is not allowed to change
void rr(B* test) {
   test->stack= malloc((4) * sizeof(A)); //4Elements
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        (test->stack+ i)->x= 89; // error cause incomplete type but i 
                                 //have to use this line       
    }
}
```

Hope now it is easier to i understand what i want

Comment: `function rr(&x);` is not proper C code, at least not without some definition for `function`. You may also be attempting to use `rr` before declaring it. You should edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: The sentence “function rr i am not allowed to change” is unclear. Do you mean you are not allowed to change any of the source code of `rr` at all? Or just that you are not allowed to change its parameter types? Or something else?

Comment: `test->stack+ i` fails because, as `stack` is declared, the compiler does not know how big the thing it points to is. `test->stack+ i` says to compute a pointer that points to `i` elements beyond where `test->stack` points, where the element type is an array of unknown size. Since the size is not known, the calculation cannot be performed. To help people answer, you should explain what you want to use `test->stack` for. If it is just to point to the first element of an array of `A` objects, change its declaration to `A *stack;`.

Comment: You have still not provided a [mre]. To compile cleanly, up until the point of the error you are asking about, your code needs `#insert <stdlib.h>` and a definition for `function`. We can easily insert the former, but you should provide the latter or remove it from the code in the question. You should also change `main()` to `int main(void);`.

Comment: Second, as you have been told, changing `A(*stack)[];` to `A *stack;` is likely sufficient. If it is not, you should explain why. You say you want a “pointer to an array of A’s”, but the standard C way to work with a pointer “to an array” in an ordinary way is to use a pointer to the first element, which has type `A *`. This **serves** as a pointer to the array in that it can be used to access the array, as with `test->stack[i]`, `test->stack[i].x`, and `(test->stack + i)->x`. Technically its type is not “pointer to array,” but colloquially we speak of it as such since it serves our purposes.

Comment: So, if you truly need `stack` to have type “pointer to array of `A`” rather than “pointer to `A`”, you should explain that. And the answer will be that it is not possible both for `stack` to have type “pointer to array of `A`” and for the expression `test->stack + i` to compile unless the size of the array is made part of the member declaration, as in `A (*stack)[4];`. But then it should not be assigned a pointer to an array of any other size.

Comment: thx @Eric Postpischil but i can't make A (*stack)[count] cause it isn't a const. or is it wrong?

Comment: Answer the questions. Show the definition of `function` and explain why `A *stack;` does not suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration:

```
A(*stack)[];
```

Says that `stack` is a pointer to an array of `A` of unknown size.  That is an incomplete type which means it can't be used directly.

It seems like what you actually want is not a pointer to an array, but a pointer to the first member of a dynamic array of `A`.  So declare the member as a pointer:

```
A *stack;
```

Comment: Thx for u' re answer. But I would have a pointer to a dynamic array of A's.

Comment: `A (*)[]` is not an invalid type.

Comment: @uecke That's exactly what the above change give you.  Try it.

Comment: I think he wants simple `A stack[]`. instead of pointer

Comment: @0___________ You can't assign a pointer to that.

Comment: Why do you want to assign the pointer?

Comment: @0___________ They're allocating space for the array dynamically.

Comment: And what is stopping them? `B *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + size * sizeof( s -> stack[0]));`

Comment: @0___________ That's not what `rr` is doing.  An instance of `B` is declared on the stack in `main` which is passed to `rr`, so space for the array of `A` needs to be assigned to a member of `B`.

Comment: @uecke You almost never want a pointer to an array of an unknown size. In particular, `test->stack+ i` would be invalid for such a pointer. Even if the size was known, it would still do the wrong thing. Use a pointer to the first element of said array instead. `test->stack+ i` does exactly what you want if `stack` is declared as `A* stack;`.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression:

```
(test->stack+ i)->x= 89;
```

before accessing an array via a pointer to an array you must dereference it.
Try:

```
(*test->stack)[i].x= 89;
```

Comment: the problem here is that i am not allowed to change this line (test->stack+ i)->x= 89;

Comment: @uecke, please add this important piece of information to the question and follow the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70214647/4989451

Comment: @tstansil thx for advice

Answer (score -1):

You do not know how to use flexible array members.

Simply:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} A;

typedef struct  {
    size_t count;
    A stack[]; 
}B;


B *createStack(size_t size)
{
    B *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + size * sizeof( s -> stack[0]));
    return s;
}

void rr(B* test) {
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        (test->stack+ i)->x= 89;        
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    B *stack = createStack(4);
    rr(stack);
    free(stack);
}
```

You need only one allocation to mallloc/realloc or free the structure. The array will decay into pointer for your assignment in `rr` function.

Comment: thx for answer but i need to have  a pointer to an array of A's

Comment: You have: Bptr -> stack is a pointer to the first element of the array. You do not need a pointer to the array

Comment: This fails the "function rr i am not allowed to change" requirement.